# String permutation statement clarification

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to understand code for checking if two Strings are permutation (case sensitive and whitespace matters, using ASCII characters). This code generates an int array and counts number of times each char appears in 's' and puts this count into the int array. And then I'm confused in the `if` statement: `if (--letters[c] < 0)`. Why decrement the count ? If the letter is not in the array then it means the count must be 0 ? However this `if (letters[c] == 0)` does not work, why ? I don't understand

```
public boolean permutation(String s, String t) {

    if (s.length() != t.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    int[] letters = new int[256]; // Assumption

    char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();

    for (char c : s_array) { // count number of each char in s.
        letters[c]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++) {
        int c = (int) t.charAt(i);
        if (--letters[c] < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sort s,t if equal, permutation.

Comment: I did this and it works but this was another alternative in the book that I'm trying to understand

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code you posted uses the array as a form of hash table.
It basically saves the ascii int value of each character (0-255) and as it goes over the first string it increments each character accordingly.
So abca is 97,98,99,97 so the array will have

```
letters[97] = 2,  
letters[98] = 1,  
letters[99] = 1
```

So as it goes over the second string `t` if there are more occurrences of a character the decrement will go bellow 0 and so it is not a permutation.
So a,a,b,c is 97,97,98,99

```
letters[97] = 2 -1 -1 = 0,  
letters[98] = 1 -1 = 0,  
letters[99] = 1 - 1 = 0
```

**But** a,a,a,b which is 97,97,97,98

letters[97] = 2 -1 -1 -1 = -1,
letters[98] = 1,
letters[99] = 1

So not a permutation.

This is a nice snippet but works only for ascii strings

Comment: Brilliant explanation and example, exactly answers the question, thanks !

Answer (score -2):

```
 if (--letters[c] < 0) {
     return false;
    }
```

In previous step you have already incremented the chars on respected positions.
Now to cross check the other string, you reduce the same corresponding locations.If the no of char's on same location are exact, it will leave a exact 0.

> *"why letters[c] == 0 does not work"*

Well because the corresponding any previously non-occupied position will be by default 0. Means, when in case a non-matching char, you will decrement the char's location which will be 0-1 = -1 <0 .

**Update**

There is only one common array : letters. You are incrementing the count at the specific char location 1st.For eg. if it is `{'1','2','3'}` then you increase locations : `letters[49]++ ,letters[50]++,letters[51]++`. Now lets take other string as : `{'1','2','3','4'}` : in this case: `letters[49]-- ,letters[50]--,letters[51]--` the all will be 0 again. but for char '4' we will have `letters[52]--` which is < 0. here is mismatch.

Comment: Reasons for down-voting?

Comment: I am incrementing the count only not the position, the locations start from 0 in both the array and the for loop

Comment: What I was lacking which is mentioned in the accepted answer? Do you really have courtesy for those who give you an answer ? Or simply you don't want to understand ? @Frugo

Comment: I have never downvoted your answer. Why don't you try to learn to calm down. Thank you for your input.